# Windows 10 boot loop during setup of new Notebook (HP Pavillon 15)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, windows-installation

I recently bought a new notebook, a HP Pavilion15-ab216ng (i7-5500U + 450GB SSHD). It came without Windows (only Free DOS), so today I tried to install it.

Setup went fine, I removed all partitions from the harddrive, created a new 100GB windows partition and allocated the rest for data. After the reboot, it shows the normal messages after a install (setting up hardware etc) and then the circle just spins around endlessly (not stuck), but no error message.

When I reboot the notebook, the same happens again. I tried reinstalled Windows 10 with another iso, but it still ends in a boot loop.
Suggestions?

Comment: "and then the circle just spins around endlessly" how long did you leave it set at that screen?

Comment: around two hours

Comment: All I can suggest is to see if it generates any setup log files and look at those....https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824819.aspx